# NServiceBus: Messages handled multiple times

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

I am at a complete loss as to why I am experiencing this problem. I am new to NServiceBus and have so far set up a dead simple 'server' which listens for messages sent by a web application. The server asks for custom initialisation (IWantCustomInitialization) and uses a [custom builder for Castle Windsor 2.5.1](http://blog.paulhadfield.net/2010/09/updating-nservicebus-to-use-another.html). This custom builder is basically a copy of the one that comes with the NServiceBus source code, with two minor changes to move away from methods deprecated in Windsor 2.5.

Note that my code shares the container instance with NServiceBus.

The problem I experience is that every message sent by the web application is processed five (5) times by the server. The log files have five entries for each attempt, with the fifth attempt looking like this:

```
2011-03-28 16:04:10,326 [Worker.8] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [] - Calling 'HandleEndMessage' on NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.NHibernateMessageModule
2011-03-28 16:04:10,327 [Worker.8] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [] - Calling 'HandleEndMessage' on Server.NHibernateSessionMessageModule
2011-03-28 16:04:10,341 [Worker.8] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [] - Calling 'HandleError' on NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.NHibernateMessageModule
2011-03-28 16:04:10,342 [Worker.8] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [] - Calling 'HandleError' on Server.NHibernateSessionMessageModule
2011-03-28 16:04:10,344 [Worker.8] ERROR NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport [] - Message has failed the maximum number of times allowed, ID=80cffd98-a5bd-43e0-a482-a2d96ca42b22\20677.
```

I have *no* indication why the message fails, and I don't know where to dig for more information/output.

The configuration 'endpoint' looks like this:

```
public void Init()
{
    container = Windsor.Container;
    NServiceBus.Configure.With().CastleWindsor251Builder(container).XmlSerializer().MsmqTransport().IsolationLevel(System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Unspecified);

    var masterInstaller = new NotificationServerInstaller();
    masterInstaller.Install(container, null);
}
```

The message handler is, at this stage, really contrived, and looks like this:

```
public class NewUserMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<NotifyNewUserMessage>
{
    private readonly IGetUserQuery _getUserQuery;

    public NewUserMessageHandler(IGetUserQuery getUserQuery)
    {
        _getUserQuery = getUserQuery;
    }

    public void Handle(NotifyNewUserMessage message)
    {
        var result = _getUserQuery.Invoke(new GetUserRequest { Id = new Guid("C10D0684-D25F-4E5E-A347-16F85DB7BFBF") });
        Console.WriteLine("New message received: {0}", message.UserSystemId);
    }
}
```

If the first line in the handler method is commented out, the message is processed only once.

I have found some posts/threads on the web (including StackOverflow) which talk about similar issues, notably http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/5977 and [Anyone using Ninject 2.0 as the nServiceBus ObjectBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406340/anyone-using-ninject-2-0-as-the-nservicebus-objectbuilder/2410105) - but I haven't had any success in making my problem go away.

I'd be most obliged for any help. I'm a n00b at NServiceBus!

Comment: I have also experienced NServiceBus handling the same message multiple times. In my case I was using Autofac2 and the reason was that I had multiple message handlers in the same assembly. (More specifically, I had multiple message handlers such that some handled a subclass of messages handled by another). It seems to me that this is "frowned" upon by the creators of NServiceBus. Do you experience the same issue if you use a different container?

Comment: @eulerfx - thanks for your quick reply. At the moment I have only one message handler in the assembly. I will quickly refactor and try with a different container to see what happens.

Comment: @eulerfx - I have the same issue even when I use the standard out-of-the-box config (with StructureMap, I think). It appears that it's only if I hit the database that this issue occurs.

Comment: Which version of NSB are you using?  What Profile are you running as?    It looks like to me that you probably have a NH SessionFactory that is conflicting with the one NSB is using for Saga persistence.  Check the container to see that you don't have multiple.  Also I recommend letting NSB set the IsolationLevel.

Comment: @Adam - Thanks for your reply. I am using NServiceBus 2.5, and I'm running the Lite profile (default, as I'm not specifying it for the generic host). Can you shed more light on how there might be a conflict between my session factory and NSB's factory for saga persistence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServiceBus isn't handling it multiple times by default it will retry 5 times if an exception occurs, you can set this in a config file. Have you got distributed transactions turned on? Because you are committing to a database and you have an open transaction (the queue transaction) when you open another transaction it will try and upgrade it to a distributed transaction, I think that may be the issue. Have you run with the console app? You should see some out put on there.

Comment: Scott, thanks very much for your reply - it provided the key to the answer. The problem was that my database _read_ was wrapped in a Unit of Work which rolled back the NH transaction. I've been sloppy and used the UoW to demarcate transactions to keep the NH profiler happy. Once I changed the use of the UoW to do the read and then _commit_ the transaction, the DTC no longer complains and the message is not put back on the queue because the distributed transaction is not rolled back. Thanks!

Comment: Got the same issue, if you use NH transaction but not explicitly commit, it is seen as a rollback. NH profiler rocks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wrapping the body of the Handle method in a try/catch and add a break point to the catch and see what is wrong.
Once you work it out, remove the try/catch.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for this. I've tried to wrap the handle method body as you suggested, but it doesn't yield anything the NServiceBus logging doesn't. In fact, there are no exceptions thrown at all.